# " error: metrics not available yet " even metrics-server is running

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am new to kubernetes and was trying to create horizontal auto scaler. For this I deployed metrics server. I used the official gitHub repository for metrics-server. I can see the process running as below

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/metrics-server-766c9b8df-dltgd   1/1     Running   0          13m

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
service/metrics-server   ClusterIP   10.106.14.34   <none>        443/TCP                  37m 

NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/metrics-server   1/1     1            1           37m
```

I deployed a pod which is running on the worker nodes and hence I can see below metrics

```
ubuntu@master:~/metrics-server$ kubectl top pods
NAME                          CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
demo-deploy-d86b8cfcc-2jg9w   2m           289Mi
demo-deploy-d86b8cfcc-5xtww   1m           284Mi
demo-deploy-d86b8cfcc-hk2bq   1m           278Mi
demo-deploy-d86b8cfcc-jkdmc   1m           286Mi
```

But issue is

```
ubuntu@master:~/metrics-server$ kubectl top nodes
error: metrics not available yet
```

I searched a lot but my bad I couldn't get answer for this. Can someone help me why it is so?

```
ubuntu@master:~/metrics-server$ kubectl top nodes
```

this should show the metrics for the worker nodes. But to my bad I am not getting it. Not even blank status.

Comment: Which kubernetes distro are you using?

Comment: 1.8+  using below repository https://github.com/MithunTechnologiesDevOps/metrics-server.git  . I searched for the official repository also but couldn't find the yaml files there .
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

Comment: Not sure that the install is the issue, but you might want to try `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml` just to get the latest from the official repo

Comment: @Gari Singh - I have already run the command you are suggesting ... after that only i am able to get the metrics related to pods ... but metrics related to nodes are not coming .

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get nodes`?
Also, what distro are you running?  Minikube, Kind, k3s, etc

Comment: ubuntu@master:~/metrics-server$ kubectl top nodes
error: metrics not available yet

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UDG52REs68

watch this video

add in spec:

command:

- /metrics-server
- --kubelet-insecure-tls
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34850589)